# VB.Net Program (Windows Service) keep down

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a program written in vb.net (VS2008, window service), I've shorten the code to make it simple like below :

```
    strSQLEquip = "INSERT INTO xxx..."
    strSQLEquip2 = "UPDATE xxx..."
    strSQLEquip3 = "UPDATE yyy..."

    If Condition = true Then
        Try
            Command = DB.GetSqlStringCommand(strSQLEquip)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@EQUIPMENT_TYPE", DbType.String, PISAlarms.PISAlarm.EquipmentType)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@EQUIPMENT_ID", DbType.String, stopID)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@ALARM_TYPE", DbType.String, PISAlarms.AlarmsType.TypeDOOR)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@TRIGGER_DATETIME", DbType.String, CurrDataTime)
            DB.ExecuteNonQuery(Command)

            Command.Connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Else
        Try
            Command = DB.GetSqlStringCommand(strSQLEquip2)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@EQUIPMENT_TYPE", DbType.String, PISAlarms.PISAlarm.EquipmentType)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@EQUIPMENT_ID", DbType.String, stopID)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@ALARM_TYPE", DbType.String, PISAlarms.AlarmsType.TypeDOOR)
            DB.ExecuteNonQuery(Command)

            Command = DB.GetSqlStringCommand(strSQLEquip3)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@EQUIPMENT_TYPE", DbType.String, PISAlarms.PISAlarm.EquipmentType)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@EQUIPMENT_ID", DbType.String, stopID)
            DB.AddInParameter(Command, "@ALARM_TYPE", DbType.String, PISAlarms.AlarmsType.TypeDOOR)
            DB.ExecuteNonQuery(Command)

            Command.Connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
```

When running in server windows service, the service keep down, I got the error in log file "Server timed out". If I remove the portion of "strSQLEquip3", means program run "strSQLEquip" and "strSQLEquip2" only, it works withou error.

Comment: There must be error in strSQLEquip3.  Check Again

Comment: We're not your personal assistants. Asking people to email you a solution is inappropriate behavior here. Answers will be posted here, in response to your question, in the space provided below. If you need more personalized attention, hire a contractor and pay them to provide it. We can't tell you what might be wrong with `strSQLEquip3`, because you've not shown us what it contains or what it does. I suppose it's related to whatever the real SQL update statement does other than `UPDATE yyyy....`.